# How to write Latex of the picture given

Tags: overleaf, physics

[image]

How to write Latex for the picture given.

Comment: `B_y\bigr|_{\mathrm{axis}} =`  If you want the line taller, you could change `\bigr` to `\Bigr`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Please check out these two sources: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics (\right) and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics . // Please feel free to share your results :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}        
        B_{y}\big |_{axy}=
    \end{document}
```

% Try this may work for you.

Comment: Did you test your code?